# Bible verse search: ~we all do God's will

Tags: will-of-god

I've tried several search engines...

Is there a verse that says we all end up doing God's will either as sons like [John or James] or as slaves like [rebellious people/demons]?

Comment: why do you think there is a verse that says that? is there a sermon, publication, or random person that says that?

Comment: _Wherefore God also hath highly exalted him, and given him a name which is above every name: 10That at the name of Jesus **every knee should bow**, of things in heaven, and things in earth, and things under the earth; 11And that **every tongue should confess** that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father._ Philippians 2:9-11.

Comment: @depperm - from memory, probably a decade ago so...

Comment: @Nigel J  That's a good one but doesn't have all the elements I was thinking of.

Comment: I got a little further with ChatGPT but didn't find the single verse I half remember and is probably a paraphrase.  Here's the chat link if anyone is interested: https://chat.openai.com/share/1f331bc0-f979-44a1-aa6b-3fe8ff00a28b

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: @agarza  I did as you suggested.  Some questions, like mine, are refined based on exchanges.  I'm guessing that this is the issue with my post.  This site want clear cut questions so clear cut answers can be given, graded and rewarded with points.  Considering the nebulous subject matter(codified spirituality, aka theology) this was unexpected.  Should I delete this entire post?

Comment: Your question doesn't have any downvotes (as of now) so there is no need to delete it. My "Welcome" message is mostly to acquaint new users with **how** the site operates; some new users think it is a forum like Reddit, etc.

Comment: @ agarza  I misread your intent.  Still, analytical/discursive seems suboptimal for theological discussions.  Discussion of fact is most clear in the natural sciences then increasingly hazy approaching the social disciplines.  Beyond that, how structured interpretation of the paradoxical relations between the physical and spiritual worlds commingle, empiricism seems of limited use.  imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having been a reader of the Bible for over 60 years now, I'm going to stick my neck out and answer with an emphatic, **"No, the Bible nowhere says that all humans all do God's will."** That is the wording of your main question.

However, you then go on to modify that by asking if "we all ***end up*** doing God's will", either as sons, or as slaves. ***That changes the question entirely.*** The biblical answer, I suggest, is that the day will eventually come when, as the prophet Jeremiah foretold (31:31-34), the knowledge of God shall cover the Earth as the waters cover the sea, and nobody will need to be taught the things of God, for they will all know that. However, that lies in the future after God declares:

> "For, behold, I create new heavens and a new earth: and the former
> things shall not be remembered, nor come into mind... For as the new
> heavens and the new earth, which I will make, shall remain before me,
> saith the Lord, so shall your seed and your name remain... all flesh
> shall come to worship before me, saith the Lord. And they shall go
> forth, and look upon the carcasses of the men that have transgressed
> against me: for their worm shall not die, neither shall their fire be
> quenched; and they shall be an abhorring unto all flesh." Isaiah 64:17
> & 66:22-24 A.V.

Jesus gave further insight into that future time, especially with the account of the rich man dying and finding himself in torments, while Lazarus the beggar died and found himself in bliss, in the bosom of Abraham. Read Luke 16:19-31 for the details. Those who never wanted to do God's will in this life will find themselves unable to do it in the next. The same with the demons who are already outside of God's will and shall forever more be alienated from God (James 2:19, Matthew 8:28-32).

Yet, of a truth, it will transpire that on the awesome Day of Resurrection and Judgment, every living creature will submit to God's sovereign Lordship by doing this:

> "Wherefore God also hath highly exalted [Christ Jesus] and given him a
> name which is above every name: that at the name of Jesus every knee
> should bow, of things in heaven, and things in earth, and things under
> the earth; and that every tongue should confess that Jesus Christ is
> Lord, to the glory of God the Father." Philippians 2:9-11 A.V.

Ah, but **those demons and unwilling subjects who were not brought into the family of God by faith, and who refused to do God's will shall then go to their eternal state of anguish** as described in Revelation chapter 20. Do read all of it, for that will give you the final outcome.

Comment: @Mark No Bad Cake. To me it sounds like something you might have heard someone say and is actually not a Biblical verse. Sort of like someone saying, "God helps those who help themselves." This statement is not in the Bible.

Comment: @Anne  Yea, "do God's will" should have been stated as contribute to God's overall plan directly as sons/daughters or indirectly as slaves.  Thanks for your response and I will take a look at the verse in Luke as well as the others.

Answer (score 2):

Doh!, I found it -not a Bible verse. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Per The C.S. Lewis Bible, NRSV:

> I could well believe that it is God’s intention, since we have refused milder remedies, to compel us into unity, by persecution even and hardship. Satan is without doubt nothing else than a hammer in the hand of a benevolent and severe God. **For all, either willingly or unwillingly, do the will of God: Judas and Satan as tools or instruments, John and Peter as sons.**
> —from a letter to Don Giovanni Calabria, September 20, 1947
> For reflection John 13:2

John 13:2

> The devil had already put it into the heart of Judas son of Simon Iscariot to betray him.

Comment: @ agarza  Thanks for the edit recommendations.  I originally couldn't figure out how to reduce the amount of bold type.  I need to read up on Markdown formatting evidently.

Comment: Well done for finding the quote you'd heard long ago! Obviously, not in the Bible, but a comment C.S. Lewis made about John 13:2 with regard to Judas and Satan. +1